# Combine unequal length lists to dataframe pandas with values repeating

Tags: pandas

How to add a list to a dataframe column such that the values repeat for every row of the dataframe?

```
mylist = ['one error','delay error']
df['error'] = mylist
```

This gives error of unequal length as df has 2000 rows. I can still add it if I make mylist into a series, however that only appends to the first row and the output looks like this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'col2': [3, 4, 9, 11, 17], 
    'error':['one error',np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

However I would want the solution to look like this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'col2': [3, 4, 9, 11, 17], 
    'error':[''one error','delay error'',''one error','delay error'',''one error','delay error'',''one error','delay error'',''one error','delay error'']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have tried `ffill()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to the result of `df.to_numpy()`. Note that you'll have to use `[mylist]` instead of `mylist`, even though it's already a list ;)

```
>>> mylist = ['one error']
>>> df['error'].to_numpy()[:] = [mylist]
>>> df
   col1  col2        error
0     1     3  [one error]
1     2     4  [one error]
2     3     9  [one error]
3     4    11  [one error]
4     5    17  [one error]

>>> mylist = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> df['error'].to_numpy()[:] = [mylist]
>>> df
   col1  col2            error
0     1     3  [abc, def, ghi]
1     2     4  [abc, def, ghi]
2     3     9  [abc, def, ghi]
3     4    11  [abc, def, ghi]
4     5    17  [abc, def, ghi]
```

Comment: i would want to add the entire list which contains more than one element to every row ...

Comment: Oh, I see! One moment...

Comment: @Sayonti check the answer now. Hopefully I've understood :)

Comment: i dont think this would work as you are assuming the column 'error' to already exist, in this case i am trying to create a new column called error from mylist and thus the above way would give you a key error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very clean way to do it, but you can first update your `mylist` to become the same length as the rows in dataframe, and only then you put it into your dataframe.

```
mylist = ['one error','delay error']
new_mylist = [mylist for i in range(len(df['col1']))]

df['error'] = new_mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the elements in `mylist` exactly N times where N is the ceil of quotient obtained after dividing length of dataframe with length of list, now assign this to new column but while assigning make sure that the length of repeated list don't exceed the length of column

```
df['error'] = (mylist * (len(df) // len(mylist) + 1))[:len(df)]
```

---

```
   col1  col2        error
0     1     3    one error
1     2     4  delay error
2     3     9    one error
3     4    11  delay error
4     5    17    one error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(error=mylist.__str__())
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?